# Bad HTTP status code: 422

Tags: python-2.7, tornado

I'm writing a REST API using Tornado

trying to use

```
raise tornado.web.HTTPError(422)
```

get this error

```
Bad HTTP status code: 422
```

Please help to solve this problem

Comment: Yes, you got the error you raised... sounds like everything's working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With source of the web.py being as follows:

```
if e.status_code not in httplib.responses:
   logging.error("Bad HTTP status code: %d", e.status_code)
   self.send_error(500)
```

Shall we suspect that 422 is not regarded as an appropriate status on tornado?

Comment: Ok I'll try to explain. I need to return this code, even if it is not in httplib, you can not do?

Comment: Are you writing a WebDAV server? Because if not, this is the wrong code. If you must have it, try self.write_error(422) instead of raising.

Comment: `self.set_status(422, reason='Need to set 422')`